# Split string into Ysubn strings

Tags: python

I have a string, say [ADSOKFJACP]. I want to divide this into substrings given a value N. So if N = 2, I want to out put 2 strings y1 = [ASKJC], y2 = [DOFAP]. If N = 3 it should output 3 strings Y1,Y2,Y3, with each one holding every 3rd letter. Y1 = [AOJP], y2 = [DKA]...

How can I do this for python?

Comment: Please demonstrate a reasonable effort to solve it yourself first, then post any **Python** code you have so far to be assisted if needed.

Comment: @Tomerikoo The split in that question is different, I'm not sure how to go about doing it so that I can create multiple strings.

Comment: Break down your problem into steps. `n` tells you how much strings you will have. It also tells you the step between the letters. Try to create one string first (maybe with slicing?) And when you get that, think how you can create all of them according to `n` (maybe with a `for` loop?).

Answer (score 0):

One solution using `itertools`:

```
from itertools import zip_longest, islice

s = 'ADSOKFJACP'
N = 3

out = {}
for i, v in enumerate(map(''.join, zip(*zip_longest(*(islice(s,i,len(s),N) for i in range(N)), fillvalue=''))), 1):
    out['Y{}'.format(i)] = v

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
{'Y1': 'AOJP', 'Y2': 'DKA', 'Y3': 'SFC'}
```

---

For `N = 2` the result is:

```
{'Y1': 'ASKJC', 'Y2': 'DOFAP'}
```

---

EDIT (Simpler version):

```
s = 'ADSOKFJACP'
N = 3

out = {}
for n in range(N):
    out['Y{}'.format(n+1)] = s[n::N]

print(out)
```

Comment: That's a very un-readable way for doing `s[i::N]`...

Comment: @Tomerikoo Yeah, you have right :) I updated my answer.